# What is this open pipe below the basement floor?

Tags: basement, pipe, drain, sewer, canada

We are doing our basement floor, and when we removed the old carpet I found the box depicted in the picture. The main pipe is clearly the main drain going to the sewer, so no worries there. But there is this other opened vertical pipe at the bottom of the pit (upper left on the picture), which I cannot imagine what it is good for; any hints?

*(there is also this other pipe that seems to drain into the box, but as far as I can tell it is not connected to any actual drain in the house)*

[image]

Comment: Is it possible that is a sump for draining the foundation ? I did not think sewer cleanouts could be in the same well as a sump but that may be a local thing.

Comment: Is there a floor drain in your basement? Does the loose plug in the well fit that pipe or is it an extra part?